# PHP Excel custom currency format does not sort properly

Tags: sorting, format, phpexcel, currency

Can somebody explain me please how to set up currency in PHPExcel? I have a cell value which is formated like a string "1 234 567 €". So I set the formatCode this way:

```
$sheet->setCellValue($col . $row, $value);
$sheet->getStyle($col . $row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode( '# ### €');
```

The result is well formatted but when I tied to sort it(OpenOffice, LibreOffice), it sorts like a string not like a numbers. It means 2 > 10. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to set cell value as float or integer instead of string. Without any currency signs, spaces, commas... Format is for presentation purpose in result file. Also the format should looks like # ##0 € cause "#" digit placeholder will suppress the display of insignificant zeroes. a "0" digit placeholder will always display a digit.

PS: As I see format with comma separated decimals '# ##0,00 €' does not work. It has to be '# ##0.00 €' with dot as a separator.